# What is the difference between a Collection and a Map?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

What is the difference between a Collection and a Map?

Would Map be a subclass of Collection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the JavaDoc of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

From the JavaDoc of [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html):

> A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements. [...] The JDK [...] provides implementations of more specific subinterfaces like Set and List.

The two interfaces are *not* related from a class hierarchical point of view, i.e. `Map` does not extend `Collection`, nor does `Collection` extend `Map`. That said, both interfaces are part of the [Java Collection Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the freely available [source code](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) from the JDK or if you don't have that, JavaDoc for [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you'll see that both are interfaces which define an API for objects which hold other objects.

The JavaDoc explains this better than I can... 
From the `Collection` JavaDoc: *"A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements."*

And from the `Map` JavaDoc: *"An object that maps keys to values."*

Contrary to what some of the other answers indicate, `Map` has a different API and is not one of types that extend `Collection`, like `List`, `Queue` and `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements. Some collections allow duplicate elements and others do not.  Some are ordered and others unordered.

An object that maps keys to values.  A map cannot contain duplicate keys. Each key can map to at most one value.

Answer (score -2):

Map is a more specific version of a Collection that has a Key -> Data structure.  Collection is just the interface that has data structures for storing data in Java.

Answer (score -2):

A map is a collection.

Collection includes Lists, Sets and Maps.

Lists are: Vector, ArrayList, LinkedList
Sets are: HashSet and TreeSet
Maps are: HashMap and TreeMap

A map is a list of key-value pairs.

Answer (score -3):

The difference between Maps and Collections is that they are two distinct things with pretty much nothing in common. One is not a sub-class of another.

Comment: Map *is* a collection.

Comment: @iluxa It's a shame you're being downvoted by folks who don't realize that Map does NOT implement the Collection interface.

Comment: i know, right :) Well hey, at least my programs work! :)

Comment: I'm not talking about inheritance. Collection is simply any object holding other objects. Maps hold . So map is a collection. When you say they are two distinct things you would be wrong.

Comment: I'm not talking about inheritance. A collections is merely an object that contains other objects. Maps, arrays, lists and others containers are collections. If you mean map does not implement collection interface you should just say that, and I'd be happy to remove my down vote.

Comment: In java, the word collection has a very strict meaning attached to it. And the word map. And also the word 'is'. Its generally better if you don't assign three meanings to the same word, better chance you get understood. Arrays are not collections. Containers come from awt and are also not collections...